# Display a clickable link on screen in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to display a link which is stored in a variable, on the screen with a custom message. All of this is inside one function.

I have tried using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') but that doesn't work as I cannot access the url variable from inside the html file.

Code in main.gs:

```
function writeScript() {

    var zipFileId = XYZ; 
    //Then there's a bunch of code to calculate zipFileId

    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + zipFileID;

    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h3>URL</h3>" + url);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Script Download');

}
```

Is there a way to display, in the final dialog box the text "URL" which is clickable and takes me to the link stored in the variable url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for adding a link to www.google.com.

```js
function clickableModal() {
  var url = "https://www.google.com";
  var htmlString = "<base target=\"_blank\">" +
    "<h3>URL</h3><a href=\"" + url + "\">CLICK ME</a>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlString);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Script Download');
}
```

As to accessing the `url` variable from inside the html file, look at the documentation for [HTML templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), as that allows you to do just that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste into Code.gs:

```
function showDialog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
  html+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">';
  html+='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></head><body>';
  html+='<div id="msg"></div>';
  html+='<script>$(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(hl){document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=hl;}).getUrl();});</script></body>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Loading a URL')
}

function getUrl() {
  var zipFileID='something';
  var url='https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + zipFileID
  return Utilities.formatString('<a href="%s">Clickable Link</a>',url);
}
```

Run showDialog();